# Does a password that's cracked someone's account increase the chances of cracking someone else's account?

Tags: reference-request, passwords, dictionary-attack

For every find in password that cracks someone's account, does that particular password have a higher probability of cracking someone else's account more than a brute force dictionary choice?

How novel are people's password choices in relation to other people's?

Curious if there are papers about this. There's probably a higher probability that the same password is used for all accounts by the same user but what I'm curious is if a group of passwords that are known to crack x # of users have a higher chance of cracking other users' passwords than just random choices from a dictionary.

I guess I'm curious about if there's increased frequency of that password showing up more than a random choice of word.

Comment: If a good KDF is used correctly (salt etc.), no. Other than that, I do not really think this question relates to cryptography (maybe it suits information security SE better).

Comment: Nvm. I googled KDF and got nothing related but got it when I searched KDF salt :). Thanks will read about it.

Comment: I'm probably not smart enough to understand fully what this KDF is and also I guess I wasn't very clear about my question (probably also because I don't really know much about information security as Aleph suggests this problem is.) But I guess I realized the question itself might be a stupid one considering that using a dictionary of words already implies those choice of words or character combinations have a higher probability of being someone's password.

Comment: A good password hash helps, but does not completely prevent dictionary attacks. It reduces the size of the search space  (usually significantly), but that's it.

Comment: KDF means key derivation function. However, I do not think that the use of a KDF does affect the answer to your question very much. But I agree that the question should probably be asked on http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: yes, many people use the same lousy passwords (ala 123456). football teams always make the top 100 lists. in fact, crackers run known previously-used password rainbows before dictionaries, to get all the low-hanging fruit. there's also predicatable sub-patterns; if users are made to use an uppercase and a digit, they usually begin the pw with the uppercase and put the digit at the end...

Comment: see https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WPny7wk960 for more info